# I have disabled the DVD on my IBM Thinkpad, now it will not start

Tags: thinkpad, chkdsk

I was having issues with the DVD on my IBM thinkpad so I foolishly decided to disable it. Now it will not boot. After starting it,a blue screen comes up and tells me to run the "chkdsk /F" command,  but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am Technotarded and should have known better than to disable anything.

My question is:

**How do I get my computer back to working again?**

Comment: (1) How have you disabled the DVD, (2) describe better the blue screen. You could edit your post with the new data, and also add a comment below to inform me of it. (Note: precede the comment with @harrymc so I would get notified.)

Comment: It would also be good to know what model thinkpad it is. It sounds likely to be a problem with your hard drive; there are probably testing utilities you can run, but how you get them depends on what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you describe indicates corruption in the data structure of the volume's filesystem layout.  Something appears to be in violation of the NTFS (or FAT) standard.

This really has nothing to do with the DVD drive being disabled.  (It may have something to do with the computer being restarted-- an improper shutdown could lead to this.)

The first step to fixing the issue that is being reported is to back up any important data.  Chkdsk /F will feel free to make changes to the disk, and will try to correct issues.  The process is kind of like erasing data from a chalkboard, and writing new values.  Hopefully the process works.  If it doesn't, Chkdsk might actually cause more problems than it fixes, and keep doing that until everything is fixed, or it realizes that it doesn't know how to keep trying.  This could potentially cause many more problems, so try to salvage any important data first.  (In theory, you should back up data anyway.  But, *especially* now.)

The next step is to try to get to a command prompt (which should be in the system menu, under Programs/Applications, possibly under Windows System Tools or something like that.  A "Windows Command Prompt" or "PowerShell" will do.  Then, type:

`CHKDSK /F C:`

The other approach is to use the graphical interface.  The exact steps may vary based on what version of Windows you have, but here is a rough approximation for 21st century options: go to Explorer so you can see all your drives.  Right-click on the desired drive, and choose properties.  On the Tools tab, use the Error Checking option.

Go ahead and re-enable your DVD at any time.  This has nothing to do with the Chkdsk error.  (How to re-enable it depends on how you disabled it; maybe a BIOS setup option, or through Device Manager.)